# Validating the existence of 350 million files over a network

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table with around ~300,000,000 absolute UNC paths and I'm trying to (quickly) validate each one to make sure the path in the SQL Server table actually exists as a file on disk.

At face value, I'm querying the table in batches of 50,000 and incrementing a counter to advance my batch as I go.

Then, I'm using a data reader object to store my current batch set and loop through the batch, checking each file with a `File.Exists(path)` command, like in the following example.

Problem is, I'm processing at approx. 1000 files per second max on a quad core 3.4ghz i5 with 16gb ram which is going to take days. Is there a faster way to do this?

I do have a columnstore index on the SQL Server table and I've profiled it. I get batches of 50k records in <1s, so it's not a SQL bottleneck when issuing batches to the .net console app.

```
while (counter <= MaxRowNum)
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT id, dbname, location FROM table where ID BETWEEN " + counter + " AND " + (counter+50000).ToString();

    connection.Open();

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var indexOfColumn1 = reader.GetOrdinal("ID");
        var indexOfColumn2 = reader.GetOrdinal("dbname");
        var indexOfColumn3 = reader.GetOrdinal("location");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var ID = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn1);
            var DBName = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn2);
            var Location = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn3);

            if (!File.Exists(@Location.ToString()))
            {
                //log entry to logging table
            }
        }
    }

    // increment counter to grab next batch
    counter += 50000;

    // report on progress, I realize this might be off and should be incremented based on ID
    Console.WriteLine("Last Record Processed: " + counter.ToString());
    connection.Close();
}

Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.Read();
```

EDIT: Adding some additional info:

thought about doing this all via the database itself; it's sql server enterprise with 2tb of ram and 64 cores. The problem is the sql server service account doesn't have access to the nas paths hosting the data so my cmdshell runs via an SP failed (I don't control the AD stuff), and the UNC paths have hundreds of thousands of individual sub directories based on an MD5 hash of the file. So enumerating contents of directories ends up not being useful because you may have a file 10 directories deep housing only 1 file. That's why I have to do a literal full path match/check.

Oh, and the paths are very long in general. I actually tried loading them all to a list in memory before I realized it was the equivalent of 90gb of data (lol, oops). Totally agree with other comments on threading it out. The database is super fast, not worried at all there. Hadn't considered SMB chatter though, that very well may be what I'm running up against. – JRats 13 hours ago

Oh! And I'm also only updating the database if a file doesn't exist. If it does, I don't care. So my database runs are minimized to grabbing batches of paths. Basically, we migrated a bunch of data from slower storage to this nimble appliance and I was asked to make sure everything actually made it over by writing something to verify existence per file.

Threading helped quite a bit. I spanned the file check over 4 threads and got my processing power up to about 3,300 records / second, which is far better, but I'm still hoping to get even quicker if I can. Is there a good way to tell if I'm getting bound by SMB traffic? I noticed once I tried to bump up my thread count to 4 or 5, my speed dropped down to a trickle; I thought maybe I was deadlocking somewhere, but no.

Oh, and I can't do a FilesOnNetwork check for the exact reason you said, there's 3 or 4x as many files actually hosted there compared to what I want to check. There's probably 1.5b files or so on that nimble appliance.

Comment: Couple of obvious things which may help. 1. Don't close the connection between loops (minimal but every little helps). 2. Try and multi-thread the code, e.g. a simple way could be give 4 threads a range of 75m ids each

Comment: For one thing I'd read batches from the DB into an in-memory list, then use multithreading for checking the UNC. Look at .NET tasks for how to do this.

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is SQL and not just disk speed?

Comment: Agree on the multithreading! Make each thread responsible for its own step like `Select * from table where pagenumber = @iteration * @threadNumber` (roughly)

Comment: As far as I can see, the bigger bottleneck must be the disk reading speed. Have you thought about loading available filenames in to a memory list and then update your table as `file available` ?

Comment: *A completely (not really) off topic comment* : Grab an SSD.

Comment: Is there anything common about file paths? E.g. say they are all on one drive or something? You could then just load all files in a folder and then check your db records instead of calling File.Exists.

Comment: Oh, I probably should've added the storage subsystem is a 10tb nimble appliance, so it's pretty darn fast.

Comment: 10tb surely means a harddisk which can *almost* never be fast enough.

Comment: @JRats: Have you tried loading file names to a list(s)? How long does it take?

Comment: A SAN can be fast in multiple ways. Maybe yours has great throughput but high latency. What you're doing though is generating TONS of SMB traffic. There was a question lately why .NET generates so much SMB traffic, there are ways to decrease that significantly, but I can't quite find it yet.

Comment: Looking at your  code again, I strongly feel that you can achieve a significant performance gain if you switch your logic. On a side note, the `ID` column must be an `index`. Load all available file locations in to a few lists, read them in multiple threads and pass the file location as a parameter to a SP. Which means you will be calling the SP in multiple threads.

Comment: By the way, can you also explain _why_ you need to check the existence of this many files, and how often you're supposed to do so? Can't you do it at the moment a user requests a (partial) file (list) from your application? Can't you fix the "disconnection" between filesystem and database at the point where users add or delete files in your system, and flag the database record appropriately?

Comment: Unrelated to the main problem, but still relevant. Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use parametrized queries.

Comment: @CodeCaster, apologies, I should've been more specific, it's a one off job because we migrated data to a new storage subsystem.

Comment: verify 350 million files? This a one shot deal or will this happen weekly/monthly/yearly? Is this network share one location, or many? Option to create a local client on the remote machines?

Comment: Yes you can do an all files check.   At 3x to 4x as many files it still may be faster.

Answer (score 20):

Optimizing the SQL side is moot here because you are file IO bound.

I would use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to obtain a list of all files that exist. Enumerating the files in a directory should be much faster than testing each file individually.

You can even invert the problem entirely and bulk insert that file list into a database temp table so that you can do SQL based set processing right in the database.

If you want to go ahead and test individually you probably should do this in parallel. It is not clear that the process is really disk bound. Might be network or CPU bound.

Parallelism will help here by overlapping multiple requests. It's the network latency, not the bandwidth that's likely to be the problem. At DOP 1 at least one machine is idle at any given time. There are times where both are idle.

---

> there's 3 or 4x as many files actually hosted there compared to what I want to check

Use the `dir /b` command to pipe a list of all file names into a .txt file. Execute that locally on the machine that has the files, but if impossible execute remotely. Then use `bcp` to bulk insert them into a table into the database. Then, you can do a fast existence check in a single SQL query which will be highly optimized. You'll be getting a hash join.

If you want to parallelism the `dir` phase of this strategy you can write a program for that. But maybe there is no need to and dir is fast enough despite being single-threaded.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Dump a list of all the files (from the NAS) to a file, BCP that to a sql table, then do a comparison against my existing set of UNC paths in the current sql table. That's a good idea, but how do you handle sub directories with the dir command? There's hundreds of thousands of sub directories deep. Sometimes only containing a single file. This is an intriguing idea however...

Comment: Right now, I've got a build running that's split my result set over ~50 threads; I adjusted my task scheduling strategy and that seemed to be the sweet spot to keep CPU utilization high without I/O bounding me, or so it seems. Gona let that run overnight and check on progress. I did add a bit column for "HasBeenChecked" on my sql table so that I'm at least making some progress, but I'm limiting runs to the database to very large batch sets utilizing my indexed columns; it didn't cause any slow down in testing by doing so, and this way I'm re-entrant.

Comment: What's the problem with the sub directories? dir is recursive with /S. What are your perf goals actually? Is this a one off thing that is supposed to be done within a week? In that case probably the simple dir+bcp solution is all you need. Otherwise, use C#+SqlBulkCopy for the directory enumeration and parallelize the former. Bulk inserts should get you like 200k rows per second per core.

Answer (score 11):

The bottleneck most likely is network traffic, or more specifically: SMB traffic. Your machine talks SMB to retrieve the file info from the network storage. SMB traffic is "chatty", you need a few messages to check a file's existence and your permission to read it.

For what it's worth, on my network I can query the existence of about a hundred files per second over SMB, while listing 15K files recursively takes 10 seconds.

What *can* be faster is to retrieve the remote directory listing on beforehand. This will be trivial if the directory structure is predictable - **and** if the storage does not contain many irrelevant files in those directories.

Then your code will look like this:

```
HashSet<string> filesOnNetwork = new HashSet<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(
                            baseDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

foreach (var fileToCheck in filesFromDatabase)
{
    fileToCheckExists = filesOnNetwork.Contains(fileToCheck);
}
```

This may work adversely if there are many more files on the network than you need to check, as the filling of and searching through `filesOnNetwork` will become the bottleneck of your application.

Comment: Funny. The same answer.

Comment: This kind of processing requires multiple threads. So it's important use thread safe collections. Reading file locations from the database table is a waste. Instead OP should update the availability status.

Comment: @usr yeah, the logical one. ;) Can you explain how parallellism may solve a network bottleneck?

Comment: By overlapping multiple requests. It's the latency, not the bandwidth that's likely to be the problem here. At DOP 1 at least one machine is idle at any given time. There are times where both are idle.

Comment: @usr ah, like that. Sure. I'm not sure how OP's storage will handle  that, and they'll have to carefully measure what approach works best. I can imagine that from a certain number of parallel `File.Exists()` requests hitting the server, the operations slowing down altogether.

Comment: @Kosala comparing two string collections can indeed be faster when done multi-threaded, but this is "pseudo" that OP can improve if required.

Comment: @CodeCaster: There is no need to compare 2 lists. All you need is pass the disk file path to a StoredProc and get the stored proc to update the availability status.

Comment: @Kosala well that depends, do you want to pass an array of 350 million records to an SP call? And then loop in that SP to find the appropriate database record for each path? Or perform 350M SP calls? Then you're just moving the problem. Granted, to a database engine, which is better designed for such tasks, but then still.

Comment: Could bulk insert to temp table, then join. Will result in hash join. But selecting data in bulk is faster than writing data in bulk. Can easily be order of magnitude according to my experience.

Comment: @CodeCaster: You don't have to past all 350 million file locations at once. You have to break the collection in to segments and call the SP for each segment. DBs are designed to do that. It will be significantly faster than reading from the database.

Comment: @Kosala sure, that is _an_ option. Feel free to post that as  your own answer, I chose this pretty naive approach as a starting point for OP.

Comment: @user: You have to be very careful with temp tables here. You can kill the database server with this much data,.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am avoiding giving an answer to this question. All we can give him is some ideas. I have given my opinion already. OP has to do a lot of work by himself in this case.

Comment: @Kosala yeah actually it is "unclear/too broad" because there are way too many unspecified variables, causing almost any suggestion to be possible, but nevermind that. I think it's upvoted because OP mentioning the large number of files only, but I do think it's an interesting problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster Fully agree with you on that one. I upvoted OPs question as soon as I read it.

Comment: You should use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` in the `HashSet` when storing file paths.

Comment: @Lucas wel no, if case sensitivity is a problem (i.e. the casing in the database differs from that on the filesystem), I'd uppercase the entries and needle on beforehan.

Comment: @CodeCaster Upper casing adds time.  Pick a StringComparer that matches the db collation is faster.

Comment: @Frisbee why do you think so? A comparison of one record to 350M records will have to do the case-insensitive comparison for every record and every needle. That is relatively slower, because "a" will have to be compared against "a" and "A", while with performing that conversion on beforehand, it only has to happen once.

Comment: Test.  My experience is string comparer is very very fast and beats upper on the front end.

Comment: @CodeCaster It is a HashSet.  Your assertion it will perform a comparison (case sensitive or not) for every record is false.   Take a million random strings with random case and put them in Hash string ToUpper and also a Hashset string case insensitive.  Then do a contains on all those random.  You will have to do a ToUpper again for the the ToUpper.  You really think the ToUpper will be faster?

Comment: Yeah, I actually thought about doing this all via the database itself; it's sql server enterprise with 2tb of ram and 64 cores. The problem is the sql server service account doesn't have access to the nas paths hosting the data so my cmdshell runs via an SP failed (I don't control the AD stuff), and the UNC paths have hundreds of thousands of individual sub directories based on an MD5 hash of the file. So enumerating contents of directories ends up not being useful because you may have a file 10 directories deep housing only 1 file. That's why I have to do a literal full path match/check.

Comment: Oh, and the paths are very long in general. I actually tried loading them all to a list in memory before I realized it was the equivalent of 90gb of data (lol, oops). Totally agree on threading it out. The database is super fast, not worried at all there. Hadn't considered SMB chatter though, that very well may be what I'm running up against.

Comment: Oh! And I'm also only updating the database if a file doesn't exist. If it does, I don't care. So my database runs are minimized to grabbing batches of paths. Basically, we migrated a bunch of data from slower storage to this nimble appliance and I was asked to make sure everything actually made it over by writing something to verify existence per file.

Comment: Threading helped quite a bit. I spanned the file check over 4 threads and got my processing power up to about 3,300 records / second, which is far better, but I'm still hoping to get even quicker if I can. Is there a good way to  tell if I'm getting bound by SMB traffic? I noticed once I tried to bump up my thread count to 4 or 5, my speed dropped down to a trickle; I thought maybe I was deadlocking somewhere, but no.

Comment: Oh, and I can't do a  FilesOnNetwork check for the exact reason you said, there's 3 or 4x as many files actually hosted there compared to what I want to check. There's probably 1.5b files or so on that nimble appliance.

Comment: @JRats That is a whole lot of information not in the question

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, it was things in my brain that weren't quite translating to paper at 4 am. :)

Comment: @JRats I have added a concrete approach to my answer given this information. Ideally, you would edit all this info into the question. It's a bit awkward to fish that information from a long comment stream (on another answer).

Comment: You know, it sounds really dumb, but I wasn't aware I could actually do that. ;) Excuse the newbie, I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 3):

On your current solution getting batches of 50,000 and open and closing the connection serves NO purpose but to slow things doen.  DataReader streams.  Just open it once and read them all one at a time.  Under the covers Reader will send batches at a time.  DataReader won't try and jam the client with 300,000,000 rows when you have only read 10.

I think you are worried about optimizing the fastest step - reading from SQL

Validating a file path is going to be the slowest step

I like the answer from CodeCaster but at 350 million you are going to get into object size limits with .NET.  And by reading into a HashSet it does not start working until that step is done.

I would use a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) with two collections

- enumerate files
- write to db

The slowest step is read file names so do that as fast as possible and don't interrupt.  Do that on a device *close* to the storage device.  Run the  program on a SAN attached device.

I know you are going to say write to db is slow but it only has to be faster than enumerate file.  Just have a binary columns for found - don't write the full filename to a #temp.  I will bet dollars to donuts an (optimized) update is faster than enumerate files. Chunk your updates like 10,000 rows at a time to keep the round trips down. And I would do the update asynch so you can build up the next update while the current is processing.

Then in the end you have check the DB for any file that was not marked as found.

Don't go to a intermediate collection first.  Process the enumeration directly. This lets you start doing the work immediately and keeps memory down.

```
foreach (string  fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
{
   // write filename to blocking collection
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick idea if CodeCaster's approach doesn't work due to there being too many files on the remote servers, and if you are able to install new programs on the remote servers: Write a program that you install on every server, and that listens to some port for HTTP requests (or whichever web service technology you prefer). The program that queries the database should batch up the file names per server, and send a request to each server with all the file names that are located on that server. The web service checks the file existence (which should be fast since it is now a local operation) and responds with e.g. a list containing only the file names that actually did exist. This should eliminate most of the protocol overhead and network latency, since the number of requests is greatly reduced.

Answer (score 0):

If I will do such task, I know that the bottlenecks are:

1. disks access latency (~1ms)
2. network access latency (for 100mbps ~0.2ms)
3. database limited by disk

The fastest thing is cpu cache, the second fast is RAM.

I assume, that I could use additional database table to store temporal data.
Database where now data i will call main database.

I will do to tasks in parallel:

1. recursive directory reading and save to second database in chunks for about 50k files.
2. get chunks of records from main database, and compare ONE chunk to ONE table from second database - all files not found will write to third database (and mark exists files in first database).
3. after all chunks from main database compared to second database - check all chunks from third database with second database and delete files found.

At the end in third database will only left non exist files, so i could just get strings from it and mark data in main database.

There could be additional improvements, could discuss if interest.

Answer (score 0):

How about sorting the locations as they are retrieved from the DB (db's are good at sorting).  Then the checks can be benefit from cached directory info in the cifs client,

you could get the directory-listing for the next row in the result-set, then check that row for existence in the dir-list, then repeat checking if the next row in the result-set is in the same directory, and if so check the already fetched dir-list, if not repeat outer loop.

Comment: have you tried adding an order by clause to the sql?  your edits above imply that the files are in very deep hierarchies with only one file per directory.  which granted will diminish the performance boost, but by ordering the locations, it will change the traversal of the hierarcy from random, to something close to depth-first traversal.   this will mean the leading portion of the locations will be the same, and the file system layers can better utilize any internal caching. also the physical hard disk head seek time should be reduced if the data is being read from near by.